# psql shell function mishandles parameter

Tags: shell, psql

Attempting to create a shell function to dump lookup tables from the command line. This is my base command (labels changed to conceal identity):

```
me@mypc:~$ psql -h psql.example.com -U me mydb -c "SELECT usertype_id,name,slug FROM tbl_usertype ORDER BY name"
```

I would think that this would be the corresponding shell function:

```
me@mypc:~$ function slugs() { psql -h psql.example.com -U me mydb -c "SELECT $1_id,name,slug FROM tbl_$1 ORDER BY name"; }
```

However, my function apparently puts my argument at the end of the command instead of at the $1 tokens:

```
me@mypc:~$ slugs usertype
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "usertype" ignored
ERROR:  relation "tbl_" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT _id,name,slug FROM tbl_ ORDER BY name;
```

How do I code this correctly?

Comment: What shell is this exactly and what version? If you prefix "psql" with "echo", i.e. `echo psql -h ...`, what's the output?

Comment: GNU bash 4.2.24(1)-release. The output is "psql -h psql.example.com -U me mydb -c SELECT usertype_id,name,slug FROM tbl_usertype ORDER BY name".

Comment: So it's OK when you echo the command, but not when you run it. Bizarre.

Comment: ... and it works fine for me with the function you wrote. I think you need to show the non-anonymized function, because the anonymized one you posted is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works perfectly fine on my system.

```
$ function slugs() { psql -U craig regress -c "SELECT $1_id,name,slug FROM tbl_$1 ORDER BY name"; }
$ slugs 1
ERROR:  relation "tbl_1" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT 1_id,name,slug FROM tbl_1 ORDER BY name
```

with:

```
bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

so either you've got a local bug in your older bash version, or more likely the real problem is hidden by the anonymization of the function.